# Getting 'TypeError: this.jsObject.database is not a function'

Tags: flutter

When I try to use the dependency firebase_database: ^8.0.0 I receive the error displayed in the title. I'm not sure what this error is communicating and I haven't seen to many things about it online.

Comment: you better paste the error here.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely getting this because you haven't added the scripts for firebase. It's in the FlutterFire docs right here
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/web#add-firebase-sdks